# Navigation menu just like the one in Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

How can I get the same menu that is being used in MediaWiki itself (the one on the left). Is there any extension that I can download to be installed into my own MediaWiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the collapsible menus used on the MediaWiki site ( http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki ), you will have to download and install the UsabilityInitiative extension.

http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UsabilityInitiative

Part of the extension is the new Vector skin, which contains collapsible menus.

Answer (score 2):

The sidebar is editable. Just type **MediaWiki:Sidebar** into your search field. Any administrator can edit it.

See also [Wikipedia's example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki%3aSidebar).

Comment: @auroius - you are very welcome, thanks for accepting. You may be interested in this proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wikispeedia

Comment: I'm really sorry for the wrong comment, it should've been the other answer.

Comment: @aurorius - darn (hits head on table). No problem.